# Are there examples of complex functions where converting them to the form $\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}$ is nontrivial?

Tags: complex-analysis

I just read the following proposition on Conway's "Functions of one complex variable":

> [image]

So for some functions already in the form $\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}$ we get a good hint that it might have a pole at $z=a$, that is: They could already be written in the form that reveals the order of the pole. Are there examples of complex functions where converting them to the form $\frac{g(z)}{(z-a)^m}$ is nontrivial?

Comment: How about the gamma function? Of course it always depend on your notion of nontrivial...

Answer (score 1):

If $f\colon\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is defined by $f(z)=e^{z^2}+2\cos(z)-3$, then$$
f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=f'''(0)=0.
$$So, the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $0$ is of the form $a_4z^4+a_5z^5+\cdots$ (actually, $a_4=\frac7{12}$). So, if $g(z)=a_4+a_5z+a_6z^2+\cdots$, then
$$
f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z^4}.
$$
Is such an example what you had in mind?

Comment: Good, this works!